# Search for keyword in String

Tags: java, string

I want to write a method that returns true if a keyword is found in a string and false if not. I figured out how to do so but when the keyword is something like "cat" and the string is "There is a caterpillar on a lead" it returns true even though the cat is not in the string.
What am I doing wrong?

```java
public boolean containsWord(String message, String keyWord) {
    if(message.contains(keyWord)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code its hard to tell!

Comment: Add what youo hv tried.

Comment: Have you considered using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: Do u realise why it does nto work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. The issue is that when you use contains(), it looks for that subtext in the full string but you want to look at words only.

So split your string into a list/array of words using `space` as a separator. Then Check if your array/list contains the word.

```
public static void main (String ...args) {
        String input = "There is a caterpillar on a lead";
        String wordToFind = "cat";

        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);
        boolean exists = Arrays.asList(split).contains(wordToFind);
        System.out.println(exists);
}
```

Comment: If the string is: `one cat, two dogs` and I split on space and search for `cat`, will that be found?

Comment: remove special characters before split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to solve your problem. You want to find *cat* with no characters around it. If you translate that in regex, you will get:

```
\\Wcat\\W
```

Here `\W` means a *non-word character*. *A non-word character consists of all characters except* `[a-zA-z_0-9]`.

So basically *we are looking for 5 characters, a non-word character followed by c-a-t and last character is again a non-word character*.

Here is the code to do so:

```
String str = "My favourite animal are cat, dog and mice.";

//Set the regex
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\Wcat\\W");
//Set the string
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

//Check for a match
if (matcher.find()) System.out.println("Word found at index: " + matcher.start());
else System.out.println("No match found!");
```

Output:

```
Word found at index: 23
```

I hope I have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid running through the String as an Array.

This will waste time, especially on long texts, when you have to run throughit.
But you can add an Empty Char at the beginning and search for your keyWord with having an empty string at the beginning and the end.

```java
    public boolean containsWord(String message, String keyWord) {
        return " ".concat(message).concat(" ").contains(" "+keyWord+" ");
    }
```

Does it in one line.

Comment: It will not work for `one cat, two dogs`.

Comment: I checked the Question. He was searching for a keyword, not a keyphrase.
But anyway: make keyWord as keyWord.trim() and it will work for the whole pharse including whitespace before and after.